# Let $f(x,y)=2x-4\frac{y}{x}$, $f(0,0)=0$. Show that $f$ is not Lipschitz.

Tags: lipschitz-functions

> Let 
>   \begin{align}
> f(x,y)&=2x-4\frac{y}{x} \\
> f(0,0)&=0,
> \end{align}
>   for $|x|\leq 1$, $0\leq y\leq x^2$.
>   Show that $f$ is not Lipschitz.

I calculated its derivative and it is unbounded, but I don't know hot to prove it by definition since every path I chose, like $(0,0)$ and $(x,x^2)$ is Lipschitz with constant $2$, thanks.

Comment: I'm just an undergrad student so I may be in the wrong here, but we learned that $f$ is Lipschitz on $S \subset \mathbb{R}^2$ iff it's derivative (with respect to $x$ or $y$) is bounded on $S$. Having proved that the derivative is not bounded leads to the desired result.

Comment: @Toni1234 that is only true, if $f$ is differentiable (and $S$ is convex or at least connected).

Answer (score 0):

The function $f$ is Lipschitz continuous (w.r.t. to the Euclidean norm) on the domain 
$$ D=\{ (x,y) : |x| \le 1, 0\le y \le x^2 \} $$
if and only if there exists some $L$ such that for every $(x,y), (\tilde x, \tilde y)\in D$ it follows
$$ |f(x,y) - f(\tilde x, \tilde y)| \le K \|(x,y) - (\tilde x, \tilde y)\|. $$
That is, the quotient
$$ \frac{|f(x,y) - f(\tilde x, \tilde y)|}{\|(x,y) - (\tilde x, \tilde y)\|} $$
is bounded for $(x,y) \ne (\tilde x, \tilde y)$.

Let $x\in(0,1]$. Then, we have
$$ \frac{|f(x,x^2) - f(x, 0)|}{\sqrt{|x-x|^2 + |x^2 - 0|^2}} = \frac{4x}{x^2} = \frac4x \to \infty$$
for $x\to 0$.
So $f$ is not Lipschitz continuous.